# C# delegate throwing an exception

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I thought I had done my research and figured this out, but when I try to pass data from one form to another, the program throws an exception. I'm using a delegate to try to call a function in one form from another. Here's the code I have.

In the parent form:

```
private void viewListToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmDataView dataview = frmDataView.GetInstance();

    if (dataview.Visible)
        dataview.BringToFront();
    else
    {
        dataview.GotoRecord += GotoRecord;
        dataview.Show();
    }
}

private void GotoRecord(int index)
{
    Current.record = index;
    loadRecord(index);
    setNavButtons();
}
```

In the child form, I'm trying to call GotoRecord in the parent form with the following code:

```
public partial class frmDataView : Form
{

    AdvancedList<ScoutingRecord> displayedData = new AdvancedList<ScoutingRecord>(Current.data);

    // Set the form up so that only one instance will be available at a time.
    private static frmDataView _instance;
    public static frmDataView GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new frmDataView();
        return _instance;
    }

    public delegate void GotoRecordHandler(int index);
    public GotoRecordHandler GotoRecord;

    private void dgvMain_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int row = e.RowIndex;

        int teamnumber = (int)dgvMain.Rows[row].Cells["TeamNumber"].Value;
        int matchnumber = (int)dgvMain.Rows[row].Cells["MatchNumber"].Value;

        ScoutingRecord sr = Current.data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TeamNumber == teamnumber && x.MatchNumber == matchnumber);
        //int index = Current.data.IndexOf(sr);
        GotoRecord(Current.data.IndexOf(sr));
    }
```

Whenever I run the code, it throws the following exception:

> GotoRecord was null

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Are you sure that `GotoRecord was null` is the actual exception message? That's not a standard message...

Comment: It simply looks like there are no subscribers hooked on the event. Microsoft prescribes a standard way of calling event handlers. C# 6 has nicer workarounds though. Just google Clean Event Handler Invocation - John Skeet has a good article on it.

Comment: If the call to `frmDataView.GetInstance()` returns with the Visible property set to true, initially, the GotoRecord event would never be assigned (and would be null)

Comment: DavidG, I cut and paste the exception  message. Will look at the other suggestions tonight. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eugène suggested:

```
GotoRecord?.Invoke(Current.data.IndexOf(sr));
```

or if on an older version and not using other threads:

```
if (GotoRecord != null)
{
    GotoRecord(Current.data.IndexOf(sr));
}
```

EDIT: Corrected mistake in call.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and was frustrated as it wasn't working either. There was an error in the suggestion Troy, however that wasn't my issue. For anyone looking at this answer int he future, the syntax should be:

'GotoRecord?.Invoke(Current.data.IndexOf(sr))'

However, the root my problem was that I had duplicate functions for calling opening the child form, and I was working with the wrong one. I feel a little foolish about that, but I learned a better way to work with event handlers, so it worked out. Thank you